# How do you determine if the following rings have any non-trivial ideals? $\mathbb{ℤ}_4$; $\mathbb{ℤ}_{11}$; $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, I first assumed that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ would have $2\mathbb{Z}_4$ as an ideal, but then wasn't sure how that would work with $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.  I have no idea how to attempt if $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ has any non trivial ideals.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ notice, that it is a field, because $11$ is prime, and fields only have trivial ideals.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$. If $1$ is $I$, then $I=R$.

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$. If $(a,b)$ is in $I$ and $a \neq 0$, then $(1,0)=(\frac{1}{a},0)(a,b)$ is in $I$. Similarly if $(a,b)$ is in $I$ and $b \neq 0$, then $(0,1)$ is in $I$. This means that if $I$ contains elements whose first component is non-zero as well as elements whose second component is non-zero, then $(1,1) = (1,0) + (0,1)$ is in $I$ and hence $I=\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore the only non-trivial ideals of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ must be of the form $I=0\times S$ or $I=S\times 0$ and hence must be $0\times \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\times 0$ respectively (since they contain $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ respectively as explained above).